# Blue dot doesn't appear in geolocation (Ionic 3)

Tags: geolocation, ionic3

I'm making an app using the plugin "Geolocation", everything is ok, I can geolocate myself but I don't see a blue dot (like in google map) or just a marker to show the actual position in the map. Someone can help me ? Here is my function to show the map in the View.

```
showMap(){
  this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    let mapOption = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 18,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, mapOption);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  }
);}
```

Thank you.
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8VMi.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is **no native way** of setting a dot (as in native MKMapView) for the current location. But as described in the Ionic Docs for [Geolocation plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/), you can watch for location changes and get the current latitude and longitude:

```
let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
watch.subscribe((data) => {
  // data can be a set of coordinates, or an error (if an error occurred).
  // data.coords.latitude
  // data.coords.longitude
});
```

Then you set a custom marker on the current location.